# Auto Py To Exe gets stuck while trying to convert

Tags: python, kivy, auto-py-to-exe

I'm trying to convert a project into an .exe file using auto-py-to-exe. It starts converting and then just runs for ever, with millions of lines in the console. It's not getting stuck - it is still printing lines in the output console for auto-py-to-exe, but is taking so long I can only assume it is never going to complete it. I even tried leaving it overnight to no avail.

I have tried exporting it as both One Directory and One File, and have also done the same for Console Based and Window Based. It doesn't seem to output any errors, but just runs continually.

I've tried placing the output file in the root for the main.py file and I've tried placing it in a seperate folder on my desktop. I have also uninstalled auto-py-to-exe. I am running python 3.10.

Here is a minimum replicable version - the file is called main.py and is in its own folder with nothing else in:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout()
        button = Button()
        root.add_widget(button)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
        app = MyApp()
        app.run()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        input("Press enter.")
```

Here is a link to the output after about an hour:
[text](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rh1n1jt73o4otbaref3oa/Py-To-Exe-Output.txt?rlkey=g5g1u00po9zv11r8r2hw76nvf&dl=0)